# Как работать с растровыми изображениями в .NET 7?

Tags: c#, .net, изображения, .net-7

Я собираюсь сжимать/разжимать и хешировать растровые изображения. Какую библиотеку мне стоит использовать для работы с растровыми изображениями в .NET 7? System.Drawing.Bitmap работает только в виндовс. Мой проект открытый.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action

Comment: [.NET Core Image Processing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-image-processing/). 6 библиотек. Попробуйте все. Статья от 2017 года. Возможно, какие-то либы заброшены и не развиваются.